# Automatically source configuration when running Singularity container with "shell" command

Tags: singularity-container, apptainer

I use a Singularity/Apptainer container (build from a definition file) to build the code of my project.
The way I use it is to run the container with `singularity shell my_container.sif` such that my workspace is mounted in the container and then run the command for building there.

For the build to work, I first need to source a configuration file which sets up the environment, creates some aliases, etc.  This configuration file is part of the container.  So currently inside the container I do the following:

```
> source /setup.bash
> build_command
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make Singularity/Apptainer automatically source that `/setup.bash` file when I run the container with `singularity shell`.  I tried with the `%environment` section in the definition file but it does not seem possible to create aliases there.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases don't get inherited between subshells, so it's not currently possible to pass those through `$SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT` or `%environment`.

One option is to convert the aliases to functions:

From:

```sh
alias build_command='pushd build_dir && ./configure && make && make install && popd'
```

To:

```sh
build_command() { pushd build_dir && ./configure && make && make install && popd ; }
export -f build_command
```

However, Singularity uses `/bin/sh` by default for the initial environment processing and Debian-based systems have `/bin/sh` symlinked to `/bin/dash` and dash does not support export functions to subshells that I have found. You might be stuck manually sourcing a file with the aliases/functions if using an OS in the Debian family.

---

<s>In the `%post` section of your definition, you can echo into `$SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT`.</s>

[From the docs](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/definition_files.html#post):

```
%post
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
    NOW=`date`
    echo "export NOW=\"${NOW}\"" >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
```

In your case, you would do `echo "alias something='something else' >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT`. It is important to do the append redirect `>>`, as you don't want to clobber the existing environment file.

Comment: This seems to have the same problem as the `%environment` section: It is indeed sourced when opening the container (I verified by adding an `echo`) but the alias created there is not present in the actual shell that is opened.

Comment: Ah, that's right. The shell is launched with `exec` to takes over the PID but using only the exported environment. Aliases are never inherited by subshells. You can use functions instead of aliases and export those with `export -f func_name`. However, debian-based images will still have problems in that `/bin/sh` is symlinks to `/bin/dash`, which does not support `export -f`.